# How do I multiply a QVector3D with a QMatrix3x3?

Tags: c++, qt, matrix, vector, qt3d

This question may sound absolutely trivial but this line of code doesn't run since there's no operator * defined for QVector3D and QMatrix. I've looked at the doc and it doesn't seem to be there. Is there any way to do this? If no, is there a specific reason?

```
QVector3D r_new = QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D::crossProduct(r, n), 45).toRotationMatrix() * r;
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading some documentation, it appear that the operator* is defined between a QVector4D and QMatrix4x4. So I used QVector4D instead and got something like:

```
Qt3DCore::QTransform transform;
transform.setRotation(QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D::crossProduct(r, n), -30));
QVector4D r_to_4D = QVector4D(r, 1.0);
r_to_4D = transform.matrix() * r_to_4D;
QVector3D r_new = r_to_4D.toVector3D().normalized();
```

there are clearly claner way to write it, but I'll stick to that for now.

Answer (score 0):

As you only want to apply a rotation to the 3D vector, it looks like you can do that directly with the QQuaternion::rotatedVector method - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquaternion.html#rotatedVector

```
QQuaternion R = QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D::crossProduct(r, n), 45);
QVector3D r_new = R.rotatedVector(r);
```